# Como enviar texto por email pelo mail.php inserindo texto campo $header sem perder a formatação quando recebe email

Tags: php, email

Tenho um arquivo `mail.php` e esta funcionando bem, porem gostaria de escrever um texto maior no assunto quebrar linha etc, mas quando envio o email chega com as formatações aparecendo, como faço para que a mensagem chegue com quebra de linha de forma normal.

Segue o arquivo envia.php

```
<?php

    $nome = 'Emerson';
    $email = 'teste@teste.com'; // e-mail do destinatário
    $assunto = "<p><b>$name</b> enviou um arquivo mensagem:</p>
    <p><br>Número do Pedido: 8 ";
    
    
    
    $headers = 'From: email@meudominio.com.br'; 
    
    $headers = 'Date:'.date('r');
    
    mail($email, $assunto, $headers, $from)

?>
```

vejam como chega no corpo do e-mail:

```
<p><b></b> enviou um arquivo mensagem:</p> <p><br>Número do Pedido: 8
```

Deveria chegar assim:

```
enviou um arquivo mensagem:
Número do Pedido: 8
```

Alguem sabe como solucionar?

Comment: Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site. Vale notar que num cliente normal de email a linha do assunto usualmente é única - teria que verificar se está testando em algum lugar que suporta quebra antes de qq coisa..